# How to remove a location from Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I was looking for restaurants in my home town and I found one that closed some years ago (in fact it changed its name and now it is completely different). Is there any way to notify this to Google?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can report the error to Google from the marker on the map.

- After you search for a place, click the appropriate marker. The info window appears.
- Click Edit > Report a problem.
- Select the issue that pertains to this place and add any comments you have.
- Click Report a problem. Google will investigate the place you have reported.

[Taken from this help article](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=98014)

**UPDATE**

It appears that you can't report it then.  I've had a look around but there doesn't seem to be a simple "Report here" link.

[This is from a help article that can be found here](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171429)

> If the Edit or Report a problem link
>   is greyed out or doesn’t exist, this
>   means that you’re not able to tell us
>   about these issues just yet. Don’t
>   worry, we’re working hard to make this
>   available in all countries!

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately community edits are not available for now in Spain http://www.google.com/support/places/bin/answer.py?answer=168339